# Swift - Is there an UIImageViewDelegate?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

So I have been out of the iOS coding world for a bit and I am going through Swift at the moment.

In Objective-C I was able to change an image on the fly, but to do so I had to set the image delegate. The other reason I set the delegate was so I could hide the `UIImageView`

In Swift I seem to have an issue with this.
With the playground I can do this fine:

```
let responseImageView:UIImageView!
responseImageView.hidden = true
```

But in the project this does not work.

**Can someone help me out here?**

In my project I have this code :

```
@IBOutle var responseImageView: UIImageView!

//Inside a function I have this:
let smile = "smile.png"
imageName = UIImage(named: smile)!
responseImageView = UIImageView(image: imageName)
```

That code does not work.

And I can't hide the image by doing this:

```
responseImageView.hidden = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the actual UIImageView in the Storyboard or Interface Builder (and connected the IBOutlet correctly - it's always a good idea to double check this if something isn't working as expected!) you should not try to instantiate it again in code just to change the image. Instead, change the image by accessing the UIImageView's `.image` property, like so:

```
let smile = "smile.png"
let image = UIImage(named: smile)
responseImageView.image = image
```

## Edit:

Just to clarify: by "instantiate" I specifically mean this line from you project code:

```
responseImageView = UIImageView(image: imageName)
```

Doing this in your function will break the connection you've set up in the storyboard. If you put a break point after that line or a `println("\(responseImageView.superview)")` you'll see that your instance of responseImageView is now no longer attached to a superview (explaining why you can change it's image or hide or unhide it all you want - you'll never see any change in the app).

Comment: That is what I have done, the let part is from playground and the @IBOulet is in the storyboard - it is connected properly

Comment: @JeffKranenburg added some clarification to the answer; maybe this'll help you

Comment: Thanks for this, it made sense when I changed it to responseImageView.image = (image: imageName) with just changing the property :-)